# Can't delete an application in /Library

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, permission, vpn, library

I made the error of trusting bitdefender and now I can't delete BitDefender VPN. I tried to use `sudo chflags nouchg`, `sudo chmod 777` and then `sudo rm -rf` but my mac's response is always "*Operation not permitted*". 
The BitDefender VPN .app file's position is `/Library/Bitdefender/Central/Modules/com.bitdefender.vpn`.
How can I do to delete it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow the [uninstall instructions for Bitdefender](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-uninstall-the-new-bitdefender-antivirus-for-mac-1687.html)?

Comment: ...or the ones, when the uninstaller is missing: [Bitdefender Removal Instructions](https://www.bitdefender.vn/post/how-to-uninstall-antivirus-for-mac-if-the-standard-uninstaller-doesn-t-work)

Comment: BitDefender has an online manager structure. You can handle (un)installs from there. Managed Mac would make that harder

Comment: No, i don't want to uninstall totally Bitdefender. I want only to uninstall Bitdefender VPN, that is only a part of Bitdefender...

Comment: The instructions I linked to are done from Recovery.  You should be able to delete whatever you want from there.